# Copying image and maintain orientation?

Tags: java, javafx, io, javax.imageio

**Edit**
It turns out that the 2nd snippet is actually working but the images in question still show incorrectly in my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) for some reason.

I am trying read an image, place a watermark and save it in a different folder and the below code does a good job, but it randomly orientates my images.

```
    try {
        final Image image = ImageIO.read(file);
        int w = ((BufferedImage) image).getWidth();
        int h = ((BufferedImage) image).getHeight();

        final BufferedImage finalImage = 
            new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        //Graphics2D g = finalImage.createGraphics();
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) finalImage.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(watermark, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();

        File outputFile = new File("watermarked/" + folderName + "/" + file.getName());
        outputFile.mkdirs();

        ImageIO.write(finalImage, "jpg", outputFile);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: notify client
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After some reading I learned that `ImageIO.read(...)` does not maintain orientation or other "metadata" of the image it is processing. I also read about using the ImageReader to extract the metadata. According to the docs, using ImageReader.readall() should include the metadata in the returned IIOImage but I still end up with some of my images upside down. The below code demonstrates the copying without adding a watermark.

```
    File out = new File("watermarked/" + folderName + "/" + file.getName());
    out.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);
    ImageOutputStream output = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(out);

    Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input);
    ImageReader reader = readers.next();
    reader.setInput(input);

    IIOImage image = reader.readAll(0, null);
    // Should not be needed since readAll should already take care of it.
    IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0);
    image.setMetadata(metadata);

    ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWriter(reader);
    writer.setOutput(output);
    writer.write(image);


    System.out.println(writer.canReplaceImageMetadata(0)); // Returns false
    writer.replaceImageMetadata(0, metadata); // Results in a "Unsupported write variant" error.
```

Both code snippets reside in a method that get passed a `folderName` as a string and the actual image `file`.

**Edit**

The above snippet works and the issue is something else. In my windows folder all my images made with a `Galaxy S8` show in the correct orientation. But when I copy them to my project and open them in `IntelliJ IDEA` some are oriented differently. So I added [sanselan](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/download_sanselan.cgi) as a dependency to get more insight in the meta data of the images and the images that get a different orientation in the IDE do indeed show a different orientation in the metadata. But why aren't they oriented like that in the windows folder, am I missing a metadata field or is windows storing additional data somewhere outside the image metadata?

Comment: The orientation of JPEGs may be controlled by Exif metadata. To get the desired orientation, the images probably have to be Exif JPEGs (as opposed to JFIF JPEGs, optionally with Exif metadata), and the application must support Exif rotation (`JPEGImageReader` does not). The JPEG images from a digital camera of smart phone will be almost exclusively be Exif. To write Exif, the Exif App1 segment *must be the first* segment in the JPEG stream. The ImageIO `JPEGImageWriter` writes JFIF JPEGs by default for RGB images at least.